# c programming - Extracting string of data from file

Tags: c

I have the following task: I have a file (card) with 5 strings:

```
U98_25984nhdrwedb \n
U98_5647BGFREdand \n
U98_30984bgtjfYTs \n
U77_76498375nnnnn \n
U98_83645bscdrTRF \n
```

I need to extract to another file `image.txt` those strings starting with `"U9"`.
The below code without the memory assignment (malloc, calloc) print out the codes correctly to the screen, but it does not print the correct data to the `image.txt`, where I only get `"98_25984nhdrwedb@"`.
I think I am applying the memory allocation incorrectly, but when I use `malloc` or `calloc` (before the while loop) it gets worse and print out garbage and I cannot figure out how to set this correctly.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdint.h>
    
typedef uint8_t  BYTE;
    
int main()
{
    FILE *input_card = fopen("card","r");    //open the file for reding
    BYTE data[18];
    int i, n = 5;

    FILE* output = fopen("image.txt","w");    //open the output file for writing

    output = malloc(sizeof(data)*18);         //assign memory
    while (!feof(input_card))
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            fread(data,sizeof(BYTE),18,input_card);
            if(data[i] != 0)
            {
                if (data[0] == 'U' && data[1] == '9')
                {   
                    printf("data: %s",data);
                    fwrite(&data[i],sizeof(BYTE),18,output);
                }
                fclose(output);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(input_card);
    free(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside from the memory allocation problem you should take a look at [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/6865932)

Comment: You close the output file after the first write access. You do not check how many bytes were read at all. Your usage of `if(data[i]!=0)` is very weird. This checks the second character in first line, third characater in second line, fourth character in third line... Also for each iteration of your `while` loop you read 5 times from the file.

Comment: OT: if this is a text file you should read it line by line with `fgets`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following 2 lines from your code, the second line is incorrect:

```
FILE* output = fopen("image.txt","w");    //open the output file for writing
output = malloc(sizeof(data)*18);         //assign memory <= This is WRONG
```

The variable `output` is a `FILE` pointer. You should not allocate it using `malloc`. You should only use it if `fopen` returns it successfully, which means it has already been allocated by `fopen`.

This means you don't need this:

```
free(output); // This is also WRONG
```

Because this already freed the pointer's allocated data:

```
fclose(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

fopen() returns a FILE pointer so when you *try* to allocate memory (using malloc, that also returns a pointer) you're replacing the pointer to the FILE with something that points to memory instead of the file. Removing

```
output = malloc(sizeof(data)*18);         //assign memory
```

should make it just work.